# Display SQL results with a simple pagination

Tags: sql, pagination

I have problem in display SQL results.

I have two variables must receive their value before the search in databases.

I want to search in the database and display the results with a simple pagination.
I've try some of the codes here is working well first time, but when you move to the next page does not show next results.
I think when you load page again value variables become null.
index.php send the variable value (What are the user's choices)
index1.php result with pagination
this full index1 code :

```
<?
$dtype = $_POST['dtype'];
$city = $_POST['city'];

$cor = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM drivers  WHERE dtype='$dtype' AND city='$city' " );
$pr=mysql_fetch_array($cor); 
$orderid = $pr[ID];

if (!empty($city)) {
$rec_limit = 2;

/* Get total number of records */
$sql = "SELECT count(ID) FROM drivers  WHERE dtype='$dtype' AND city='$city' ";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
$rec_count = $row[0];

if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
   $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
   $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}
else
{
   $page = 0;
   $offset = 0;
}
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

$sql = "SELECT ID, dname, dtype,mobile,city ".
       "FROM drivers WHERE dtype='$dtype' AND city='$city'".
       "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
?>
<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow'>

<div data-role="footer">

<ul data-role="listview" data-inset='true' class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow'>
    <li>ID : <?echo $row[ID];?></li>
    <li>NAME : <?echo $row[dname];?></li> 
    <li>TYPE : <?echo $row[dtype];?></li>
    <li>CITY : <?echo $row[city];?></li>
</ul>

<?     
$sid = $row[ID];

} 

if( $page > 0  )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\""?>data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini footer-button-right ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-l"> Next </a><?
  echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\""?>data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini footer-button-right ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"> Previous </a><?

   }
else if( $page == 0 )
{
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\""  .$city.""?>data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini footer-button-right ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-l"> Next </a><?

}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last </a>";
}
}
else{

echo '
 <ul data-role="listview">

<li> can not view records </li>

</ul>

';}

?>
```

Comment: what a nice SQL injection invitation. SHow the wholoe code if you want an answer to your question. Supposing that your RDBMS is MySQL, the tip is to use LIMIT keyword in your SQL instruction

Comment: Use GET instead of POST.
`$dtype = $_GET['dtype'];`
 `$city = $_GET['city'];`

and encode dtype and city in pagination link. like: `<a href='homeurl?currentpage=1&dtype=some&city=anycity'>`

Comment: AHJeebon thanks for reply but dtype includes a long text not good include in page url.

Comment: Does dtype  come from database? if yes, then you can store that table's primary key.
long text is suitable for searching.

Comment: thanks for all i update my question